# GCP Datafusion oracle connectivity issues

Tags: oracle, jdbc, google-cloud-data-fusion

We're currently having issues setting up a connection to oracle datasources in datafusion (via jdbc) and i'm not sure if i am missing something.
Bit of a background, we had issues connecting to any data source initially so in gcp i setup a vm instance to act as a proxy server (due to it being a private datafusion instance) and used iptables to register the connections.

After this i can successfully connect to sql server datasources, on the vm instance i can ping and telnet all oracle and sql datasources.

Network connectivity tests show datafusion can connect to the proxy and also that the proxy can hit datasources on-prem.

The following pics are of my connection to oracle under namespace admin in datafusion

[image]
[image]

The ip address is of the proxy instance and the port is what was assigned in the iptable entry
Again this works for sql server. Our datateam can connect to these datasources via bigquery using odbc, but it looks like you cannot use that connection type in datafusion.

Comment: did you try with service name and not SID?

Comment: Yes i have several connections to try which are a mix of SID and service name and its the same error message each time.

Answer (score 1):

Think we have resolved the issue. We noticed the logins being used had older password versioning for oracle 10, 11 etc. Got the oracle dba to create a new user to test and connection successful instantly :)